# IE8 and Firefox CSS selector difference?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, parent-child

I am getting really weird behavior, it seems like IE8 is not handling the child selector in CSS correctly. Consider the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    ul>li {font-style: italic}
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <ul> <li>Hello </li> </ul>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This displays Hello in italics on FF, but not on IE8. If you change the selector to:

```
ul li {...}
```

It displays italic in both browsers.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

IE8 can and should be displaying this CSS declaration correctly.  Check your Compatibility View settings and confirm that you're not rendering the page in IE7 mode.

Comment: Press F12 to check what is your rendering mode (IE7 or IE8).